# How to activate device admin on google glasses?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk, device-admin

I want to disable camera on my google glasses. Is there any way to activate device admin and call DevicePolicyManager.setCameraDisabled(admin, disabled) method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android stack on Google glass doesn't support admin feature.