# How to provide System Priviliges to Android App

Tags: android, google-glass, wso2-iot

I am working on a **google-glass** project, where i have to **install/update** an app programmatically, in my Research i have following complication:

1. Getting System Dialog actions, to perform click programmatically
  In order to install programmatically, the intent leads to **System Dialog** for user permission, but its not possible to stimulate the action of System Dialog programmatically. This solution is no possible [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982298/how-to-get-action-of-system-dialong-box-programatically?noredirect=1#comment74994156_43982298)
2. Using **EMM** Solution (WSO2 IOT)
  I used **WSO2-IOT**, but since there is no [device policy manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27740677/how-to-activate-device-admin-on-google-glasses/27741493) available for **google-glass**, so even installing the agent apk wont help, as i can not avail any service provided by the EMM (WSO2 IOT), (to install or update my app)
3. Getting **System Privileges** without Root
  In order to use the following permissions:

  - <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
  - <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES"/>

  My app would require System Privileges, to silently install/delete/update the app.

According to my knowledge and research so far the only current solution is the **third solution**, that is to get the System Privileges. In order to get it, i also tried [Sigined the APK with the system certificate.](https://paulononaka.wordpress.com/2011/10/19/apk-with-system-privileges/)
Still i get the error:
`java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10056 nor current process has android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES.`
Also i have tried adding the `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system` to the manifest as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3651653/2509009)

So far there is no success with achieving it. I would like to know how can i achieve installing an app silently in the background, **with out rooting the device**.

Any suggetions that will help will highly be appretiated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you need to install/update an app in the device, you have to trigger the [Package Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) with the relevant details. But for triggering the Package Manager you must have the above permissions (android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES & android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES) thus the device admin privileges. As you said, it is impossible to automate actions for System Dialog which is prompted for getting admin privileges.

The [Device Owner](https://developer.android.com/samples/DeviceOwner/index.html) concept is also available on if there exists the device policy manager. Therefore you will have to find an alternative.

I can provide you a light-weight version of an agent which successfully enroll with the IoT server without any hassle in your google-glass. But I'm afraid it is not possible to do any tasks that will need device policy manager from it.
Please find the source here: https://github.com/milanperera/android-glass-agent

Comment: Thankyou, i agree to you. There is no DevicePolicyManager and also there is no PlayServices available in the glass.
i have't encoutered with the DeviceOwner concept yet, but i will  look into that.